# How can I pass data to thread System.in and how can I get data from thread System.out?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, io

I have one main thread and one child thread e.g. `Thread childThread`.

How can I pass data to `childThread` `System.in` and how can I get data from `childThread` `System.out`?

Comment: Threads share resources so they don't have their own pipes.  You can create pipes which can be shared between threads but this is highly unlikely to be the best solution.  Can you tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes @PeterLawrey, I have `childThread` that I want to test with JUnit. `childThread` get data from keyboard, something like commands. So when I  start `mainThread` and in this thread I start `childThread` I want to pass data to `childThread` like I input it with keyboard.

Comment: It is possible to mock out The System.in and System.out, but you are far better off designing your code so it can be unit tested.  This would also eliminate the need for a second thread.  Instead I suggest you use an interface which can be mocked out or substituted with the console.

Comment: I have integration test, I need to test my all complex where I have server and client. I run test, that named `mainThread` and two childrens in this thread: `serverThread` and `clientThread`. In `clientThread` I get data from `System.in` but when I starting test, I can't pass data directly to my `clientThread` `System.in`, I can pass only to `mainThread` `System.in`. Can I solve this problem with interface?

Comment: No. You have to change the code to use an interface.  If you have to use System.in you can hack up a replacement InputStream class and PrintStream (for out) and use thread local controls. Testing it this way is not only hard to write it's also very hard to get the interaction right so that the test is robust.

Comment: If you use an interface you won't need a client+main threads, just one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) to exchange data.
Another way is to implement [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).